# The correct UML notation for loop

Tags: syntax, uml, diagram, diagramming

I have seen two versions but from what I have learned, the only correct one is that a decision cannot go directly to an activity. Also in the picture below, the diagram on the right is IMO incorrect (UML specification wise). Is that correct?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me both diagram as correct..
BTW could you use a true modelling tools for your screen shot as [Modelio](http://www.modelio.org/) or [BoUML](http://bouml.free.fr/) or what you want... (maybe just google "UML free tool")

Comment: Yeah they are correct, but as far as I can remember, the 2 is not correct UML syntax as the step would wait for the outcoume of the decision below and would never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

There is official UML syntax, and there is pragmatism.

Yes, you are right, the second one is not really correct, a diamond node should always be closed by another diamond node. But if you use the first syntax, you lose readability, because, at first glance, one always expects the first diamond (reading top to bottom) to be the condition point.

Thus, in this kind of cases, I always forget the official sytax and use the second solution. Always be pragmatic, always prefer readability.

(By the way, actions have rounded corners, what you drew really are object nodes)